# Know the day and the month in number type of specific dates using moment

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

i'm having an array of dates in the format 'YYYY/MM/DD' for example this:
`dateArr = [2018-06-09, 2018-06-10]`. I want to create two arrays each on contains the months of the specific dates and the other one the days of the specific dates in number form.
The number of the days are:

```
const daysToNumbers = {
  Sunday: 0,
  Monday: 1,
  Tuesday: 2,
  Wednesday: 3,
  Thursday: 4,
  Friday: 5,
  Saturday: 6
};
```

and the months:

```
const daysToMonths = {
      Januray: 0,
      February: 1,
      March: 2,
      April: 3,
      May: 4,
      June: 5,
      July: 6,
      August: 7,
      September: 8,
      October: 9,
      November: 10,
      December: 11
    };
```

For example the first array contains the days like this: [6, 0] and the month like this: [5,5]
I think moment.js has some function for this like the day or the month but it did not seem to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Array#map` on the original array to convert the items to moment objects, and then use the `get()` method to retrieve the appropriate component of the date:

```js
const dateArr = ['2018-06-09', '2018-06-10'];
const momentArr = dateArr.map(item => moment(item));
const monthArr = momentArr.map(item => item.get('month'));
const dayArr = momentArr.map(item => item.get('day'));

console.log(monthArr, dayArr);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are dedicated functions to [get day's number](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/day/) and [months number](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/month/) in momentjs. Checkout [here](https://momentjs.com/docs/) for more information

```js
var date = "2018-06-09";

console.log(moment(date).day()); // get day of week number 0 to 6

console.log(moment(date).month()); // get month of year 0 to 11
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```